# Couldn't get JSON response from Java Jersey app using Tomcat or GlassFish server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee, glassfish, jersey

I have problem with my Java Jersey app. I'm writing an app with this tutorial:
http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-restful-webservice-tutorial-how-to-create-restful-webservice-in-java-part-2/
My app is almost the same as in this example expect fact that I'm using Maven to import .jar files. I also have some changes in db. I run this db on **wamp server** and I'm using **phpMyAdmin**.
My app structure is as in this pic:
[image]

Always when I run my app on Tomcat or GlassFish server I get 404 error. I checked everything, I corrected **web.xml** file, cause I had problem with Servlet. I solved several problems with GlassFish and nothing helps. 
I'm trying to run this:
http://localhost:8080/silownia_java/login/dologin
and I get 404 error, but when I run http://localhost:8080/silownia_java/hello.jsp it works, so it's probably not a problem with servers. I also try to make some changes in my db, by execute commands in **Chrome Advanced Rest Client**, it also doesn't work, I only get those errors:
[image]
I don't knot where the problem could be. I know that it's hard to guess where I have some mistakes in my code, but I need ask you for help. If necessary I can post my whole project in GitHub or just some classes or files here, just tell me what should I post.

---

**EDIT:** (web.xml from Github)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>silownia_java</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
  com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>silownia_java</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: If you haven't figured it out yet, please do post the github link. I'll check it out when I get a chance

Comment: It'd be nice if you have a look on this. [Git repo](https://github.com/Kamil-H/silownia/tree/master/silownia_java). Thank you in advance!

Comment: It looks like you're missing the `/rest/` part (before `login`) in your URL. The `rest` is set up in your web.xml as the servlet mapping

Comment: Thank you so much! I spent couple of hours, trying to figure it out and I didn't get this. Again, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the `/rest/` part (before `login`) in your URL. The `rest` is set up in your web.xml as the servlet mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So just change the URL to

```
http://localhost:8080/silownia_java/rest/login/dologin
```